How can i sent an Integer from Fragment to Fragment using ViewPager2?
I want to send an Integer from Fragment 1 "Gesamt" to Fragment 2 "Rennrad". I know that i can not send it from Fragment 1 to Fragment 2 but from Fragment 1 to MainActivity to Fragment 2. Using a Bundle to store the data and receive it in Fragment 2.
But i do not know how to send the data to MainActivity and then back to Fragment 2.
MainActivity
package com.example.fahrradapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();

    }

    protected void initViews() {
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(new ViewPageAdapter(this));
        TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, new TabConfigurationStrategy());
        tabLayoutMediator.attach();

    }
}

Fragment 1 (Gesamt)
package com.example.fahrradapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;


public class Gesamt extends Fragment {

    ProgressBar progressBarkm, progressBarhm;
    Button btnrradd, btnmtbadd, btnsave, test;
    EditText kmrr, hmrr, kmmtb, hmmtb;
    TextView percentkm, percenthm, prozentkm, prozenthm;



    //Speicher
    SharedPreferences sp;
    String finalkm, finalhm, kmprozent, hmprozent;
    Integer finalprogresskm, finalgrogresshm;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gesamt, container, false);

        progressBarkm = v.findViewById(R.id.progressbarkm);
        progressBarhm = v.findViewById(R.id.progressbarhm);
        btnrradd = v.findViewById(R.id.btnrradd);
        btnmtbadd = v.findViewById(R.id.btnmtbadd);
        btnsave = v.findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        kmrr = v.findViewById(R.id.kmrr);
        hmrr = v.findViewById(R.id.hmrr);
        kmmtb = v.findViewById(R.id.kmmtb);
        hmmtb = v.findViewById(R.id.hmmtb);
        percentkm = v.findViewById(R.id.percentkm);
        percenthm = v.findViewById(R.id.percenthm);
        prozentkm = v.findViewById(R.id.prozentkm);
        prozenthm = v.findViewById(R.id.prozenthm);

        test = v.findViewById(R.id.test);

        

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Bundle result = new Bundle();
                int kmrrzahl1 = Integer.parseInt(kmrr.getText().toString());
                result.putInt("rrzahl1", kmrrzahl1);
                
            }
        });
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        return v;

    }
}


Fragment 2 (Rennrad)
package com.example.fahrradapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentResultListener;

public class Rennrad extends Fragment {


    TextView rrkmgesamtzahl, rrhmgesamtzahl, rrkmtour, rrhmtour;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rennrad, container, false);

        rrkmgesamtzahl = v.findViewById(R.id.rrkmgesamtzahl);
        rrhmgesamtzahl = v.findViewById(R.id.rrhmgesamtzahl);
        rrkmtour = v.findViewById(R.id.rrkmtour);
        rrhmtour = v.findViewById(R.id.rrhmtour);




        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.rennrad, container);

    }
}


When i enter an Integer in EditText kmrr from Fragment 1 and i press the test Button i want the Integer to be saved in a bundle and send it to Fragment 2. In Fragment 2 the data of the bundle should be shown in the TextView rrkmgesamtzahl (and later on be added to the already existing Integer).
